# i want to send request to api when the page is loaded

Tags: reactjs

I have an api and I want to request to api when the page loads. I use useEffect, but useEffect always makes requests and I don't want it. How can I make it possible to request only 1 time when the page loads?

My code

```
  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("API_URL")
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(data=>setDatas(data.reverse()))
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("API_URL")
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(data=>setDatas(data.reverse()))
}, [])
```

The `[]` at the end defines the dependency for the useEffect hook. So an empty array defines no dependency and thus will trigger only once the component/screen loads.